# Command to continue bulk download using AWS CLI after interruption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am downloading 550gb data (~26k files) from a bucket, due to internet cut the download stopped midway and only ~3k files were downloaded which already took a lot of time due to low bandwidth. How can I start the bulk download again on cmd, leaving the files which are already downloaded in the folder and start the downloading for the rest.

I used this on cmd for starting the download:

```
aws s3 cp s3://raster/COP30/ . --recursive --endpoint-url https://opentopography.s3.sdsc.edu --no-sign-request
```

Answer (score 3):

When downloading a large number of files, especially with an intermittent Internet connection, use [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) rather than `aws s3 cp`. You can run it on the directory that you've already downloaded, and it will figure out what files it already has and only download the ones that it needs.

To the best of my knowledge the AWS CLI will not restart a single large file that fails to download. However, you can write a program that retrieves file content by byte ranges, so that is one solution. There may be a third-party program that does this for you, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: So I changed the cp to sync but it gives me this error on cmd: "Unknown options: --recursive sync". When I remove the part "--recursive" from the command, the process starts running. Will it work for my specific problem? or is there any other way to it?

Comment: The `sync` command is recursive by default. It compares the source to the destination and only copies files that are modified or missing. So, if a file is copied once, it will not be copied when the sync is run again (unless the file was modified).